Prove for every graph G that if every vertex v∈V has deg(v)≥((n+1)/2)+1 then G is 2-connected
I had a question if this is possible to prove:
Prove for every graph G=(V,E), that if every vertex v∈V has deg(v)≥((n+1)/2) then G is 2-connected.
i tried by using the theorem that if every vertex has deg(v)>=(n-1)/2 than the graph is connected. And as ((n+1)/2)>((n-1)/2) it would mean that this graph is connected as well. However, I seem to be stuck by proving 2-connectivity.
I assume you would have to prove that G contains a cycle. And for every possible G with deg(v)≥((n+1)/2) that I draw it does contain a cycle, therefore proving 2-connectivity. However, I am stuck by writing this arbitrarily.
I hope you guys can help:)
Updated proof attempt:
G is 2-connected if G is connected and if deleting any vertex v in V leaves G connected.
Assume G is not connected. Let G have 2 or more components (C1, C2, ... C_k with k in N+). Let C1 be the smallest component, therefore C1 has n1<=n/2 where n1 are the vertrices in C1. for v in V1 of C1 satisfies deg(v)=n1-1. As deg(v)>=(n+1)/2 and n1-1<=(n+1)/2, this does not satisfies the original statement. Proving that G is connected.
Assume G is 1-connected. This means there exists a v in V such that removing v disconnects G. Let G'=G-v. Let C1,C2,...Ck with k in N+ be the components of G' and assume c1 is the smallest component, therefore C1 has n1<=n/2 where n1 are the vertrices in C1. As this is the same situation as that G is not connected, which was proven a contradiction, G must be at least 2-connected.
Hence the original statement is proven.

Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post.

Sorry, this is my first time writing on this forum. I did try to add some of my thoughts, but I am also quite new to discrete mathematics, therefor quite unsure if my thoughts are even correct.

Assume the graph is not connected. Consider the connected component with the least vertices and find a contradiction by counting edges.
Next, assume the graph is only 1-connected. Delete the vertex that break connectivity, and again, consider the connected component with the least vertices.

Thank you for the tip. I have constructed the following proof which I added to the original question. Do you think this might be a correct one?
